# Error al importar mi script en python

Tags: python, revisión-de-código, pyqt5

Tengo el archivo principal y mi propia función que quiero agregar. Y me manda el siguiente error. La ruta de la función está bien y la función en el archivo principal si funciona.

```
self.lbl = QLabel(self)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QLabel(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  QLabel(str, parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
```

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import cv2

sys.path.append('./funciones')
from funciones import abrirArchivo as aF

from PIL import Image


if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    rsrcPath = ":/images/mac"
else:
    rsrcPath = ":/images/win"

#clase heredada de QMAIN Window (constructor de ventanas)

class Ventana(QMainWindow,QWidget):
    def __init__(self):#Metodo constructor de la clase

        #super().__init__()
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        QTableWidget.__init__(self)
        #QTableWidget.__init__(self)

        self.showFullScreen()  # Tamaño inicial de la ventana 800x500
        # Barra de estado
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Bienvenid@")

        menu = self.menuBar() # Objeto menuBar
        menu_archivo = menu.addMenu("&Archivo")# Menú padre
        menu_editar = menu.addMenu("&Editar")# Menú padre



        # Agregar un elemento acción al menu_archivo --- Abrir Archivo
        menuArchivo_abrir = QAction("&Abrir",self)
        menuArchivo_abrir.setStatusTip("Abrir Archivo")
        menuArchivo_abrir.setShortcut("Ctrl+A")
        menuArchivo_abrir.triggered.connect(aF._menuArchivo_abrir)
        menu_archivo.addAction(menuArchivo_abrir)

        #self.lbl.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.menuContextual)
        menuEditar_promedio = QAction("&Promedio", self)
        menuEditar_promedio.setStatusTip("Promedio")
        menuEditar_promedio.setShortcut("Ctrl+P")
        menuEditar_promedio.triggered.connect(self._menuEditar_promedio)
        menu_editar.addAction(menuEditar_promedio)

        menuEditar_sobelX = QAction("&Sobel X", self)
        menuEditar_sobelX.setStatusTip("Sobel X")
        menuEditar_sobelX.setShortcut("Ctrl+SX")
        menuEditar_sobelX.triggered.connect(self._menuEditar_SobelX)
        menu_editar.addAction(menuEditar_sobelX)

        # label
        #self.lbl = QLabel(self)

        #self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)

        promedioAction = QAction("Promedio", self)
        promedioAction.triggered.connect(self._menuEditar_promedio)
        self.addAction(promedioAction)

        #imagen = self._menuArchivo_abrir()
        #sobelAction = QAction("Sobel X", self)
        #sobelAction.triggered.connect(self._menuEditar_SobelX)
        #self.addAction(sobelAction)

    def menuContextual(self,point):
        #mostrando el menu contextual
        self.popMenuPromedio.exec(self.lbl.mapToGlobal(point))



    def _menuEditar_promedio(self):

        self.imagenOriginal = Image.open(self.nombreImagen)
        print(self.imagenOriginal)
        self.imagenPromedio = self.imagenOriginal

        width, height = self.imagenOriginal.size
        # [width,height]=image.shape
        ipixel = self.imagenOriginal.load()
        opixel = self.imagenPromedio.load()

        for w in range(width):
            for h in range(height):
                if w > 0 and w < width - 1 and h > 0 and h < height - 1:
                    r1, g1, b1 = ipixel[w, h]
                    r2, g2, b2 = ipixel[w, h - 1]
                    r3, g3, b3 = ipixel[w, h + 1]
                    r4, g4, b4 = ipixel[w - 1, h]
                    r5, g5, b5 = ipixel[w - 1, h - 1]
                    r6, g6, b6 = ipixel[w - 1, h + 1]
                    r7, g7, b7 = ipixel[w + 1, h]
                    r8, g8, b8 = ipixel[w + 1, h - 1]
                    r9, g9, b9 = ipixel[w + 1, h + 1]
                    r, g, b = ((r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5 + r6 + r7 + r8 + r9) / 9,
                               (g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5 + g6 + g7 + g8 + g9) / 9,
                               (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 + b7 + b8 + b9) / 9)

                    opixel[w, h] = (round(r), round(g), round(b), 255)

        self.imagenPromedio.save('../a2.bmp')
        self.imagenPromedio.show()

    def _menuEditar_SobelX(self,imagen):

       pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)##instancia para iniciar la aplicación--obligatorio pasar los argumentos argv,esto es obligatorio
    _ventana = Ventana()#creamos el objeto de la clase
    _ventana.show()#mostrando la ventana
    app.exec()#ejecutando la aplicación
```

Mi función

```python
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import cv2


def _menuArchivo_abrir(self):
    # prueba de imagen
    self.lbl = QLabel(self)
    self.nombreImagen, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Image", "/home/", "Image Files (*.bmp)")

    # self.cv2_imagenOriginal = cv2.imread(self.nombreImagen)

    # print("nombre", self.cv2_imagenOriginal)
    self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.nombreImagen)
    self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
    self.lbl.resize(800, 600)
    # self.lbl.
    self.lbl.show()
    #return self.nombreImagen
```

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, no es un problema de *"importación"* del script. Está complicado de entender lo que hace tu código, por lo que no hubiera estado nada mal alguna explicación sobre lo que hace.

Por concretar, lo que tienes en tu script intenta ser un método adicional del widget. No entraré en este tema ahora, pero deberías asegurarte de saber lo que estás haciendo. Esta función es un *descriptor sin referencias al tipo de la instancia que lo usa*, razón de que no funcione.

Resumo dónde está el código problemático:

```
from funciones import abrirArchivo as aF

class Ventana(QMainWindow,QWidget):
    ...
    menuArchivo_abrir.triggered.connect(aF._menuArchivo_abrir)
    ...
```

En el script:

```
def _menuArchivo_abrir(self):
    ...
```

Al importar tu script obtienes el método `_menuArchivo_abrir` que conectas a una señal.

En PyQt5 la señal `triggered` recibe un *booleano* como argumento:

> void QAction::​triggered(bool checked = false)
>
> If the action is
>   checkable, checked is true if the action is checked, or false if the
>   action is unchecked.

Por tanto, el método `_menuArchivo_abrir` recibe como primer argumento un booleano, y no una instancia `QWidget`.

En realidad, `_menuArchivo_abrir` es un *descriptor* **sin referenciar**. De algún modo tienes que enlazarlo con la instancia que te interesa, algo tal que así:

```
class Ventana(QMainWindow,QWidget):
    ...
    menuArchivo_abrir.triggered.connect(aF._menuArchivo_abrir.__get__(self))
    ...
```

Que sería equivalente a esto que pretendes:

```
    menuArchivo_abrir.triggered.connect(self._menuArchivo_abrir)
```

Tan sólo falta añadir el argumento `checked` al método `_menuArchivo_abrir` para que todo funcione:

```
def _menuArchivo_abrir(self, checked=False):
    ...
```